# HTML Table Cell Padding

Tags: html

I have table2 inside td of table1

I want tds of table2 to take the full height

I have added an example with my issue here:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1t0jd80/

```
<table align="center" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="Yellow">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>hj</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="Orange">
                <td class="White">
                    <table class="Blue">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="">
                          hhhh
                        </td>
                        <td class="Red">
                          hhhh2
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>yyg</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Note that class orange has height of 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.White` class to this to get rid of the spacing:

```
.White{
  height: 100%;
  background-color:white;
}
```

If you want to specify a height, make these changes:

```
.White{
  height: 200px; /* or whatever you want */
  background-color:white;
}

.Blue{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2ge6whz/)